# Iptables allow localhost

Tags: iptables, localhost

I want to allow localhost traffic in iptables so I added the rule

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

When I run *iptables -L* it shows me that this rule got translated into

```
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

That confuses me. Doensn't that mean that iptables allows all INPUT traffic? Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try running `iptables -L -v` instead -- this will include interface names in the output.